# Filter on __typename in GraphQL HC

Tags: c#, graphql, hotchocolate

Is there anyway to filter against the __typename of an interface? We have an interface Product with four implementations as seen in the screenshot.
On our GraphQL endpoint we have only one query being on the product interface.
Should this be split up to be one endpoint per specific type or is there any way to achieve a result to make the following query possible?

```
query {
  products(where: { __typename: { eq: "Foo" }}) {
    nodes {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you just add a type parameter and filter it yourself?